# How can I run a multiline macro over a visual selection in vim?

Tags: vim, macros

I have a file containing groups of lines of ids. I need to go through and add the same group of patterns to each group of ids. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
randomstring#morerandom
randomstring#morerandom
randomstring#morerandom

randomstring#morerandom
randomstring#morerandom
randomstring#morerandom

# pattern to add
thingA;
thingB;
thingC;
```

Assume the *randomstrings* are actually random, there can be hundreds of these lines, and the groups are all of equal size but may be larger than 3 lines. I want to insert the three *things* after the # of each group of lines. This is what the output should look like:

```
randomstring#thingA;morerandom
randomstring#thingB;morerandom
randomstring#thingC;morerandom

randomstring#thingA;morerandom
randomstring#thingB;morerandom
randomstring#thingC;morerandom
```

My initial plan was to yank the things to add into register a,b,c and to create a macro that starts at the beginning of one group, inserts each thing after the #, and ends at the begging of the next group. `^f#"apj^f#"bpj^f#"cpjj^`

I tried running this macro by highlighting the area I wanted to run over, and then doing a `:normal @q`. However, this does weird things and seems to add multiple things per line.

Is just running my macro with a number and guessing the length of the file the best way to do this? i.e. `10@q`?

Also, is there a better way to yank the things into consecutive registers, instead of manually yanking each one?

Comment: If you have 100 lines in each group how do you distribute the "_three things_" to assign?  Or is it that if you have 100 lines then you'd have 100 things as well?

Comment: @zdim the number of things always equals the number of lines per group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure there is a blank line beneath each block (including the last one), like in your sample; then you can run this:

```
:'<,'>g/\n\n/normal 2k@q
```

This should run your macro on the first line of each of your blocks, restricted to the visual selection.

Alternately, delete your visual block, paste it into a new buffer, then just use the normal macro loop (unrestricted by visual selection) to transform things, then put it back into the original buffer:

```
d:enew<CR>Pqrqqr@q@rq@rggdG:bd!<CR>P
```

(if I didn't mess up somewhere)

Comment: can you explain the :'<,'>g/\n\n/normal 2k@q part? What is the 2k doing?

Comment: `2k` goes up two lines, since searching for `\n\n` will land you on the *last* line of the block.